# How can I use Gioteck VX-4 controller in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam, hardware, gamepad, joystick

I got a Gioteck VX-4 controller on sale, and am having a few problems using it with Linux. I am trying to use it via the USB cable, but other than showing up as a Dualshock 4 controller when running `lsusb`

I can't seem to make it show up in steam however, or do anything with it in jstest. Does anyone have some suggestion as to how I can solve this? any ideas?

(This is not an original controller, but It does report itself as a dualshock 4 controller, also on windows, also on PS4) I've attempted getting the ds4drv working too, but it just does not seem to correctly pick up the controller.

Comment: Does it have a driver so it can work with Ubuntu?

Comment: Not an official one it does not look like. On windows it seems to just use the dualshock 4 driver. And their Nintendo switch controller seems to work fine on Linux (from what I've read). And again, it seems to register, in Linux, as a dualshock 4 controller.

Comment: Just because Ubuntu can see it as a piece of hardware does not mean it has the driver to make it work. I have 2 web cams that have that same issue Ubuntu can see them but without a driver they do not function.

Comment: I understand there's a need for a driver, as it turns out, this one uses the official DS4 driver. I finally made it work.

Comment: Have a look at the title of the question.

Comment: Great so installing the driver fixes it?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the DS4 driver is in the kernel and officially developed by Sony, so no. It has to do with permission on `/etc/uinput` but I'll post the solution when I get to my computer again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some clever minds in a thread on the Steam community forums i found a solution to my problem

A script made by user Giralua Indiano, and [posted](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/1693795812304458372/#c3247562523071328838) in the conversation solved it for me.

The problem is essentially one of permissions on `/dev/uinput` or `/dev/input/uinput`

It should be noted that this solution does not specifically solve my problem, but pretty much for any Dualshock 4 controller, or clone that uses the official driver.